# Add Options to a Podio Category Field

Tags: c#, podio

I am having trouble updating category fields. I see that config.settings is a jobject, which I created but I didn't do something right.

Here is what I have so far...

```
var config = new FieldConfig() { Label = "New Category", Required = false, Hidden = true};
config.Settings = new Setting
{
    Multiple = false,
    Display = "inline",
    Options = new List<Option>()
    {
        new Option { Status = "active", Id = 1, Text = "One", Color = "DCEBD8" },
        new Option { Status = "active", Id = 2, Text = "Two", Color = "DCEBD8" },
        new Option { Status = "active", Id = 3, Text = "Three", Color = "DCEBD8" }
    }
};
await GV.podio.ApplicationService.UpdateAnAppField(123, 123, config);
```

And the JSON...

```
    public partial class Setting
    {
        [JsonProperty("multiple", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public bool? Multiple { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("options", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<Option> Options { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("display", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Display { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Option
    {
        [JsonProperty("status", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("text", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public long? Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("color", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: So .... what's the question?

Comment: Hey Pavlo, the question is... how do I add an option to a Podio category field?